# Implementing a Stack<E> using Vector<E>

Tags: java, vector, stack

I am using a Stack in the following way... I have problem here in line 26:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Stack<E> {
    private Vector <E> v=new Vector <E>(1);
    public int getSize() {
        return v.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (v.isEmpty());
    }

    public E getTop() {
        return v.lastElement();
    }

    public E pop() {
        E p;
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            p = v.lastElement();
            v.remove(v.size() - 1);
        }
        /*return p; what to do here?? when stack is empty how to return and what to?* /
    }

    public void push(E p) {
        v.add(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: If is not about having your own implementation for Stack you can use java.util.Stack - this implementation throws java.util.EmptyStackException if you want to pop from an empty stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go although not really advised is to return null:

```
public E pop() {
E p = null;
if (!isEmpty()) {
    p = v.lastElement();
    v.remove(v.size() - 1);
}
return p;
```

It would be much better if you can provide a default constructor(s) for the type(s) that would be used within the stack so that you can check afterwards if an object is valid or not.

```
E p = new E(); // invalid object
```

You might want to check out the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) which provides more information on this.